# Не удаётся сделать отправку данных через Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Я создаю приложение, которое должно отправлять и получать данные через Bluetooth. Но он ломается. Я не понимаю, почему.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private BluetoothAdapter BluetoothAdapter;
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    private ListView listView;
    public static String ventilator_str;
    public static String nagrevatel_str;
    public static String pompa_str;
    public static String auto_str;

    private ArrayList<String> pairedDeviceArrayList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDeviceAdapter;
    public static BluetoothSocket clientSocket;
    ThreadConnectBTdevice myThreadConnectBTdevice;
    InputStream inStream;
    OutputStream outputStream;


    private OutputStream outStream;
    private static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private static String address = "21:13:01:80:20";  //Вместо “00:00” Нужно нудет ввести MAC нашего bluetooth


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        Switch ventil_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_ventilator);
        final Switch nagrev_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_nagrev);
        final Switch pompa_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_pompa);
        Switch auto_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_auto);
        Button SearchSrart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartSearch);
        ListView Listarray = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Arraylist);

        ventil_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включен вентилятор");
                    int ventilator = 1;
                    System.out.println(ventilator);
                    String ventilator_str = Integer.toString(ventilator);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    Log.d(TAG, "...Посылаем данные: " + Otpravka + "...");

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключен вентилятор");
                    int ventilator = 0;
                    System.out.println(ventilator);
                    String ventilator_str = Integer.toString(ventilator);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    Log.d(TAG, "...Посылаем данные: " + Otpravka + "...");

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                }
            }
        });
        nagrev_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включен нагреватель");
                    int nagrevatel = 1;
                    System.out.println(nagrevatel);
                    String nagrevatel_str = Integer.toString(nagrevatel);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    Log.d(TAG, "...Посылаем данные: " + Otpravka + "...");

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключен нагреватель");
                    int nagrevatel = 0;
                    System.out.println(nagrevatel);
                    String nagrevatel_str = Integer.toString(nagrevatel);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    Log.d(TAG, "...Посылаем данные: " + Otpravka + "...");

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                }

            }

        });

        pompa_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включена помпа");
                    int pompa = 1;
                    System.out.println(pompa);
                    String pompa_str = Integer.toString(pompa);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    Log.d(TAG, "...Посылаем данные: " + Otpravka + "...");

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключена помпа");
                    int pompa = 0;
                    System.out.println(pompa);
                    String pompa_str = Integer.toString(pompa);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    Log.d(TAG, "...Посылаем данные: " + Otpravka + "...");

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                }
            }


        });
        auto_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включен автоматический режим");
                    int auto = 1;
                    System.out.println(auto);
                    String auto_str = Integer.toString(auto);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    Log.d(TAG, "...Посылаем данные: " + Otpravka + "...");

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключен автоматический режим");
                    int auto = 0;
                    System.out.println(auto);
                    String auto_str = Integer.toString(auto);

                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    Log.d(TAG, "...Посылаем данные: " + Otpravka + "...");

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }

                }
            }
        });


        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
// С Bluetooth все в порядке.
        }

        SearchSrart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //если разрешения получены (функция ниже)
                if (permissionGranted()) {
                    //адаптер для управления блютузом
                    BluetoothAdapter = android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    if (bluetoothEnabled()) { //если блютуз включен (функция ниже)
                        findArduino(); //начать поиск устройства (функция ниже)

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private boolean permissionGranted() {
        //если оба разрешения получены, вернуть true
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN}, 0);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void findArduino() //функция для выбора устройства из списка доступных для подключения
    {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            listView = findViewById(R.id.Arraylist);
            List<BluetoothDevice> data = new ArrayList<>(pairedDevices);

            ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(data, getApplicationContext());
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    device.getAddress();
                    int i = 1;
                    String itemMAC = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().split("/", 2)[0];
                    BluetoothDevice connectDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(itemMAC);
                    try {
                        //генерируем socket - поток, через который будут посылаться данные
                        Method m = connectDevice.getClass().getMethod(
                                "createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});

                        clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(connectDevice, 1);
                        clientSocket.connect();
                        if (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
                            //если соединение установлено, завершаем поиск
                            BluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.getStackTrace();
                    }
                    myThreadConnectBTdevice = new ThreadConnectBTdevice(device);
                    myThreadConnectBTdevice.start();

                }
            });
        }


    }

    private boolean bluetoothEnabled() {
//если блютуз включен, вернуть true, если нет, вежливо попросить пользователя его включить
        if (BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 0);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static class ThreadConnectBTdevice extends Thread { // Поток для коннекта с Bluetooth

        private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;

        private ThreadConnectBTdevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            final OutputStream mmOutStream;
            try {
                bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

    public static class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> implements View.OnClickListener {
        private Context mContext;

        public static class ViewHolder {
            TextView tvName;
        }

        public ListAdapter(List<BluetoothDevice> data, Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
            ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> dataSet = (ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>) data;
            this.mContext = context;


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
            Object object = getItem(position);
            BluetoothDevice dataModel = (BluetoothDevice) object;

            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.name:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Name" + Objects.requireNonNull(dataModel).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*Snackbar.make(view, "Name " + dataModel.getName(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("No action", null).show();*/
                    break;
            }
        }

        private int lastPosition = -1;

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            // Get the data item for this position
            BluetoothDevice dataModel = getItem(position);
            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

            final View result;
            if (convertView == null) {

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
                viewHolder.tvName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

                result = convertView;

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                result = convertView;
            }

            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
            result.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;

            viewHolder.tvName.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(dataModel).getName());
            // Return the completed view to render on screen

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Основное действие происходит здесь. После каждого изменения положения Switch'a должна происходить отправка данных, но к сожалению, она не происходит...

```
ventil_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включен вентилятор");
                    int ventilator = 1;
                    
                    String ventilator_str = Integer.toString(ventilator);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключен вентилятор");
                    int ventilator = 0;
                    
                    String ventilator_str = Integer.toString(ventilator);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                }
            }
        });
        nagrev_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включен нагреватель");
                    int nagrevatel = 1;
                    
                    String nagrevatel_str = Integer.toString(nagrevatel);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключен нагреватель");
                    int nagrevatel = 0;
                    
                    String nagrevatel_str = Integer.toString(nagrevatel);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                }

            }

        });

        pompa_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включена помпа");
                    int pompa = 1;
                    
                    String pompa_str = Integer.toString(pompa);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                   

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключена помпа");
                    int pompa = 0;
                    
                    String pompa_str = Integer.toString(pompa);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                }
            }


        });
        auto_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включен автоматический режим");
                    int auto = 1;
                    
                    String auto_str = Integer.toString(auto);
                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                   

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }


                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключен автоматический режим");
                    int auto = 0;
                   
                    String auto_str = Integer.toString(auto);

                    String Otpravka = ("/" + ventilator_str + "/" + nagrevatel_str + "/" + pompa_str + "/" + auto_str + "/");
                    System.out.println(Otpravka);
                    byte[] msgBuffer = Otpravka.getBytes();

                    

                    try {
                        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }

                }
            }
    });
```

LogCat:

```
2020-08-25 19:48:57.781 6692-6692/com.example.appincubator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.appincubator, PID: 6692
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
        at com.example.appincubator.MainActivity$3.onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:199)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:156)
        at android.widget.Switch.setChecked(Switch.java:1074)
        at android.widget.Switch.toggle(Switch.java:1069)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6396)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ошибка говорит о том что вы пытаетесь отправить пустой массив байт, вы судя по коду пытаетесь посмотреть что в массиве, в логах что-то выводит перед крашем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас массив `outStream` не инициализирован (равен `null`) - надо видимо ему какое-то значение присвоить.

Очевидно, там где у вас происходит коннект, вы должны и открывать выходной поток куда вы будете писать свои байты, но судя по вашему коду этого то как раз и не происходит.